# Piping to regular commands

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell function that I can use to pipe stuff to non-PowerShell commands. For example instead of:

```
dir -r *.js | % { git checkout -- $_.FullName }
```

I want to do:

```
dir -r *.js | pipe git checkout --
```

Or something like that. Right now I have the following code which doesn't work:

```
Function pipe
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
          [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
          [FileInfo[]]$files,

          [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
          [string]$command
    )
    Process
    {
        Foreach ($file in $files) {
            if ($command -match '`$__') {
                & $command.Replace('`$__', $file.FullName)
            }
            else {
                & $command $file.FullName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How would you write this, or is there any recommended way to do this?

Comment: Personally I'd wrap each subcommand in a separate function (e.g. `Invoke-GitCheckout`) with the relevant options as parameters.

Comment: `dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`. This returns `FileInfo` objects, you'll probably want to use `$_.FullName` instead of just taking the short name which is the default for the implicit `ToString()`

Comment: I'd also recommend using a `ScriptBlock` instead of `String` for the Command. It will give you a lot more flexibility. And of course, look up `Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)` for even more fun and flexibility

Comment: I'm with @AnsgarWiechers - the parser will eat up `--` if you pass it as an argument to your `pipe` function

Comment: OK, I made few updates to reflect your comments. Maybe writing a pipable `Invoke-GitCommand` is a better idea (pgit alias?). Like `pgit checkout ...`. I prefer it to be more generic than specific to each command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
# Use this cmdlet to pipe files to regular commands
# Example:
#        dir -r *.js | select -first 3 | pipe atom
#        dir -r *.js | select -first 3 | %% devenv _ /edit
#        dir -r *.js | select -first 3 | %% git checkout

function Pipe-Command
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    PARAM(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [IO.FileInfo[]]$File,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true, Position=0)]
        [string]$Command,

        [switch]$WhatIf
    )
    BEGIN
    {
        if ($Command -match '^git ' -and !$Command.Trim().EndsWith(' _')) {
            $Command += ' --';
        }
    }
    PROCESS
    {
        $QuotedPath = "`"$($file.FullName)`""
        if ($Command -cmatch ' _ ') {
            $CommandToRun = $Command.Replace(' _ ', " $QuotedPath ")
        }
        else {
            $CommandToRun = "$Command $QuotedPath"
        }
        if ($WhatIf) {
            Write-Host "What if: $CommandToRun"
        }
        else {
            if (Get-Command Write-Information) {
                Write-Information $CommandToRun
            }
            Invoke-Expression $CommandToRun
        }
    }
    END {}
}

Set-Alias pipe Pipe-Command
Set-Alias %% Pipe-Command
```

[GitHub link](https://github.com/omidkrad/DevShell/blob/3d3bc0c7359746efffcab87de4f23cf997c39274/scripts/Pipe-Command.ps1)